# Modern core method of uploading file in Perl

Tags: perl, file-upload, cgi

I'm looking to write a script that lets a user upload an image from a webpage, for later use on that website. As per usual, all I can find is examples involving CGI.pm. Are there any core modules that I can use as a replacement?

Comment: Cgi.pm is still relevant in cgi environment. It was deliberately removed from the core in order to distance perl from ancient cgi.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution I ended up going with may not be the best, but it's functioning, and simple.

Using [cgi-lib.pl](http://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu) I can simply use

```
open(VAR, ">output/file.png");
binmode VAR;
print VAR $in{input};
close(VAR);
```

and it gets the job done.

If there are any notable problems with this, please let me know.

Comment: Ok, there's using out-of-date technology and then there's something that is positively antique. The [web site for `cgi-lib.pl`](http://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu/) hasn't been updated for almost twenty years. If you want to use CGI, then please use [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod).

Answer (score 5):

The Perl core distribution contains no modules for writing web applications. I think you probably want something based on [Plack::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Request) and [Plack::Request::Upload](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Request::Upload) (for example [Dancer2::Core::Request::Upload](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Core::Request::Upload)).

Comment: I support that suggestion but we should also mention that it's not done by a simple `use Dancer2::Core::Request::Upload;`. [CGI::Alternatives](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-Alternatives-0.15/lib/CGI/Alternatives.pm) would be a good starting point if the OP _can_ still choose which framework to use.

Comment: I hope my answer isn't read as suggesting that it's that simple. That's why I included a link to the documentation. I didn't want to go into too many details as, strictly speaking, this question is off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will look into it.